# PHP count, add colons every 2 characters

Tags: php, count, addition

I have this string

```
1010081-COP-8-27-20110616214459
```

I need to count the last 6 characters starting from the end of this string (because it could may be long starting from the begin)

Then I need to add colons after every 2 characters.

So after counting 6 characters from the end it will be

```
214459
```

After having added the colons it will look like:

```
21:44:59
```

Can you help me achieving it?

I do not really know where to start!

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [`str_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

The code is done on multiple lines for clarity, but can easily be done in a chain on one line:

```
$str = '1010081-COP-8-27-20110616214459';
//Get last 6 chars
$end = substr($str, -6);
//Split string into an array.  Each element is 2 chars
$chunks = str_split($end, 2);
//Convert array to string.  Each element separated by the given separator.
$result = implode(':', $chunks);
```

Answer (score 16):

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '$1:$2:$3', $string);
```

It looks to me though like that string has a particular format which you should parse into data. Something like:

```
sscanf($string, '%u-%3s-%u-%u-%u', $id, $type, $num, $foo, $timestamp);
$timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Or something like `'/^(.+)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '$2:$3:$4'` if he only wants the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the time:

```
$time = rtrim(chunk_split(substr($s,-6),2,':'),':');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$final = "1010081-COP-8-27-20110616214459";

$c = substr($final, -2);
$b = substr($final, -4, 2);
$a = substr($final, -6, 2);

echo "$a:$b:$c";
```