# PHP preg_replace phonenumber with dash and numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a couple of phonenumbers listed in my database with a certain way of writing.
I want to have a space after every two numbers. I thought I would do:

```
$numbers = '06-12345678';
$regex = '/(\\d{2})(\\d{1})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})/';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6', $numbers);
echo $result;
```

But this doesn't work. It just places all the numbers next to each other.

My Expected Output:

```
06 - 12 34 56 78
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Oh sorry: 06 - 12 34 56 78

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380596/php-count-add-colons-every-2-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$numbers = "06-12345678";
echo $result = preg_replace("/(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/", "$1 - $2 $3 $4 $5", $numbers);
```

regex explanation:

```
(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

- 1st Capturing group (\d{2})
- **\d{2}** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **{2}** Exactly 2 times
- **-** matches the character - literally
- 2nd Capturing group (\d{2})  //<- 4x the same
- **\d{2}** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **{2}** Exactly 2 times

output:

```
06 - 12 34 56 78
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed information. It worked fine. FYI: I had one phone number `0023-1234567`. This was outputted: `0023 - 12 34 567`. Just perfect!